# Проблема с доступом к вкладке, от которой пришел request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть примерно такой код:

```
//это background.js
//Сначала создаем вкладку
chrome.tabs.create({
    'url':'...',
    'active':false
},function(tab){
     ....
});
//Потом там происходят некие операции и оттуда приходит результат.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,callback){
    //тут куча кода
    if(/*некое условие*/){
        //тут вагон кода
        chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
        //тут еще небольшая тележка
    }else{
        //тут тоже
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id,{'url':url,'active':true});
        //ну вы поняли.
    }
}
```

На что при невыясненных мной до сих пор обстоятельствах порой прилетает такая ошибка (и на `update`, и на `remove` бывает):

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.update: No tab with id: некая цифра.

Случается довольно редко,но если начинается - то со всеми вкладками сразу (у меня по 7-10 их открыто). Вкладки при этом не закрываются/обновляются.
Если просто запустить всё заново или обновить вкладку - то всё опять работает. Повторюсь, мне ни разу не удалось искусственно это воспроизвести. Я пробовал открывать кучу вкладок,инкогнито, входить/выходить из аккаунта хрома, обновлять расширения, сворачивать браузер, переключатся между окнами,вкладками,отключать инет, ставил `window.close()` сразу после реквеста (всё во время тестовых реквестов с интервалом 10) - и ничего, воспроизвести так и не удалось. Отчего это случается и как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что могу посоветовать - это проверить, что `id`, на который ругается хром, есть в списке ids табов, созданных этим расширением. Т.е. в коллбеке метода `chrome.tabs.create()` запомнить куда-нибудь `tab.id` созданного таба, чтобы потом в случае возникновения ошибки вывести `sender.tab.id` и запомненный `tabId`. Это поможет понять направление, в сторону которого стоит копать.

Второе: есть небольшая вероятность, что с момента посылки сообщения до момента его получения `tab.id` изменился. В [chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) есть два метода, позволяющие отслеживать изменения `tab.id`. Советую повесить обработчики на события [`chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onTabReplaced) и [`chrome.tabs.onReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onReplaced). В случае, если перед ошибкой срабатывает один из этих обработчиков, значит дело именно в пререндеренге и прочих внутренних трюках хрома. Такую ситуацию нужно обрабатывать.

Втретьих: методы из списка `chrome.tabs` почти все асинхронные. `remove` и `update` - точно асинхронные. Поэтому есть некоторая вероятность того, что сообщение пришло из только что умершей вкладки.

В любом случае, существование вкладки нужно проверять, а также обрабатывать ситуацию недоступности вкладки по определенному `id`. Если таб нужен, а существующий `id` не подходит, можно воспользоваться методом [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) для поиска таба (для успешного поиска таба стоит выработать какой-то критерий).

Comment: В яблочко! Среди прочего в контент-скрипте присутствовал переход по якорю. Я проверил - это меняет id вкладки! Очевидно вы были правы, пока шел реквест - контент скрипт переходил по якорю, id менялся и я получал ошибку.

Comment: Правда воспроизвести ошибку мне всё равно не удалось, т.к. приходит уже новый id. Но я увидел, что id действительно меняется. Видимо в какой-то момент браузер подтормаживал, и реквесты шли достаточно долго.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вкладка по какой-то причине уже не существует.
Подозреваю, что ничего лучше проверки ошибки сделать нельзя.

[Аналогичная проблема.](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=48715)

Comment: вкладка существует,инфа 100%. Она открывается самим расширением и её видно невооруженным глазом. Я тоже так подумал сначала,и уделил этому особое внимание

Answer (score 0):

либо действительно не существует(точнее скрыто адблоком или другим расширением) либо отлавливать:

```
function finderror() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
        // Вкладка существует
    }
}

//вызываем её
chrome.tabs.get(tab.id,finderror);
```

Comment: А можно подробнее насчет "срыто макинтош"? Что вы имели в виду? Вкладка есть, это все наглядно видно - нажимаешь кнопку, она открывается, и бац - background скрипт её теряет. При этом сама она остается, на нее можно переключится, проверить в консоли что все отработало как надо. Хотя по сюжету её как раз надо закрыть.

Comment: подправил.  ночером печатал, тупанул.     если она открывается и скрипт её теряет, то скорее всего какоето другое дополнение. Знакомый сталкивался. я в хроме не силен. сорри.

Comment: А разве адблок может целую вкладку скрыть? Причем только от браузера. Пользователь (то бишь я) её видит

Comment: нет, тут скорее всего делает её неактивной, или браузер теряет её. только тестить. жаль что неполучается её вызвать искуственно.